# Can one generalize the fact that SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3) to higher dimensions than 2 and 3?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

SU(2) is a double cover of SO(3), i.e. there is a 2 to 1 homormphism from SU(2) to SO(3). Can we generalize this to higher dimensions than 2 and 3?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of. For $n \ge 3$ the special orthogonal group $SO(n)$ satisfies $\pi_1(SO(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ so its universal cover is a double cover known as the [spin group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group) $Spin(n)$. This group usually cannot be identified with another familiar Lie group, but there are a few small values of $n$ for which it can; these are called [exceptional isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_isomorphism). They are:

- $Spin(3) \cong SU(2) \cong Sp(1)$
- $Spin(4) \cong SU(2) \times SU(2) \cong Sp(1) \times Sp(1)$
- $Spin(5) \cong Sp(2)$
- $Spin(6) \cong SU(4)$

There are a couple of different ways to see how these isomorphisms work. One can use the [Dynkin diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_diagram#Isomorphisms) classification of semisimple Lie algebras, [Clifford algebras](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/LieGroups-2012/cliffalgsandspingroups.pdf), or just construct the maps directly and prove that they're isomorphisms. For example, the double cover $Sp(1) \times Sp(1) \to SO(4)$ can be constructed using left and right multiplication of unit quaternions acting on the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$.